# コマンドプロンプトで別アプリ上へのキーボード入力として出力したい

Tags: コマンドプロンプト

タイトルの日本語がわかりにくくてすみません。

コマンドプロンプトで出力される文字列を、
コマンドプロンプト上への表示（標準出力）でもなく、
ファイルを保存するのでもなく、
クリップボードにコピー（clipへのパイプ）するのでもなく、
別アプリ上へのキーボード入力として出力する方法はないでしょうか。

例えば、開いておいたテキストエディタに文字列が入力されていく、という感じです。

Comment: 「別アプリ」というのもコンソールアプリケーションですか？ 想定している環境、OS などは何ですか？

Comment: [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cc364423.aspx)